# Is 'families' the correct spelling?

Tags: spelling

> We will find something to suit your families needs today!

I do not know whether it should be "families", "families'" or "family's"

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners and thanks for your question. I've made a few edits to make it very clear. You're welcome to keep them or reject them if you don't like them. Usually, the more information you can give in your question the better answer you'll get.

Answer (score 2):

It can be either:

> We will find something to suit your **family's** needs today!

with the meaning "of your family" (singular)

or:

> We will find something to suit your **families'** needs today!

with the meaning "of your families" (plural; notice the apostrophe after the word)

---

However, the original sentence is incorrect.

Comment: It can also be *your **family** needs*, where *family* is used as an attributive noun—as in *household needs*. (In fact, I'd say that version, in the context of shopping, is the most common.)